# Different ways of declaring user defined types in C and C++

Tags: c, types

Defined here is an enumeration in ANSI C.

```
enum Security_Levels
{
    black_ops,
    top_secret,
    secret,
    non_secret
};
```

Now to declare s[4] of type Security_Levels , I wrote this in the main() code

```
    Security_Levels s[4];
```

And I get this error:

```
file.c: In function ‘main’:
file.c:13:3: error: unknown type name ‘Security_Levels’
Security_Levels s[4];
```

But when I declared it like this

```
enum Security_Levels s[4];
```

**IT WORKED!**

```
Security_Levels s[4];
```

**This ^Worked in C++ but throws the aforementioned error in C**

I have a similar question while using **struct** in C and C++ as well.

```
struct structure_name variable_name; //this is how it works in C
structure_name variable_name; // in  case of C++
```

So, why the difference in declaring vars of user defined types?

Comment: C and C++ are two completely different languages. Why would you expect them to behave the same?

Comment: Because the specs says so. I guess C requires explicit `struct` and `enum` to make compilers easier to implement.

Comment: Not a much better reason than "because the language says so".

Comment: @JesperJuhl: That's simply not true.

Comment: @MikeMB how not? While they share a common subset and a similar syntax, modern C++ and modern C have diverged to the point of not really being compatible. Sure, you *can* write programs that compile with both a C and C++ compiler (and have identical semantics), but then you'll be using the small  common subset that doesn't really take advantage of anything modern in either language developed in the last 25 years or so.. not really that useful.

Comment: They share a common ancestry, the c++ standard refers to the c standard in many cases, they have a lot of common types, the c++ syntax is a superset of the c syntax and the c++ standard library incorporates large parts of the c standard library. It is also relatively easy to write a non-trivial program that is both valid c and c++. The compilation model is also very similar and the list goes on. That is certainly not what I'd call "**completely** different".

Comment: @MikeMB: Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics! C and C++ have taken very different ways since C++98 and C99, even more with C++11. It is nonsense to stick to the "common ancestry" thing. With that we could also say "B" or "Rust are the same language. C does not even allow to define user-types strictly speaking (which is the reason the snippet above works different actually). Re. the "compilation model": that is the same for many other languages. And with templates, it in fact **is** different, not to mention name-mangling.

Comment: @MikeMB there are also lots of examples where identical code compiled with either a C or C++ compiler will compile in both cases but have different semantics/behaviour. That alone is enough to treat them as different languages IMHO. You have to be *very* careful if you try to write code that is both valid C and valid C++ with the *same semantics*. These days you are better off treating them as completely different IMHO.

Comment: I never said, they aren't different or that you should treat one as a superset of the other or that you even should try to write a program that has the same semantics in c and c++ (although I had very few problems with this in the past) - as you said that results in too many compromises. But calling them completely different simply overshoots the target by miles - there are too many similarities.I take the part about semantics back though: I forgot about initialization (and maybe there is something else I'm not aware of). Sorry for starting this discussion - this will be my last post about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:  because that's the way the two different languages are defined.

Longer answer:  In C, `struct` and `enum` names are in separate, distinct namespaces.  That's why you see a lot of `typedef struct s s;` type things in C code so you don't need to use `struct`.  In C++, the `struct` and `enum` (and `class`) names are part of the namespace that is defining the struct/enum (usually the global namespace).  So you can reference them without a `typedef` or keyword.

Comment: Being a novice(noob xD) in C++. I tend to ask dumb questions! Thank you for the helpful response!

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return different values in C and C++:

```
extern int T;

int size(void)
{
    struct T {  int i;  int j;  };

    return sizeof(T);
    /* C:   return sizeof(int)
     * C++: return sizeof(struct T)
     */
}
```

This is due to C requiring struct in front of structure tags (and so sizeof(T) refers to the variable), but C++ allowing it to be omitted (and so sizeof(T) refers to the implicit typedef). Beware that the outcome is different when the extern declaration is placed inside the function: then the presence of an identifier with same name in the function scope inhibits the implicit typedef to take effect for C++, and the outcome for C and C++ would be the same. Observe also that the ambiguity in the example above is due to the use of the parenthesis with the sizeof operator. Using sizeof T would expect T to be an expression and not a type, and thus the example would not compile with C++.

From Wikipedia.

Comment: Copying verbatim from another source isn't the best way to create an answer.